# PDF & values of a random variable

Tags: probability

Let $X: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a random variable and $f_X(x)$ its probability density function.
Is it true that $\{x : f_X(x) = 0\} \cap X(\Omega) = \emptyset$?

For one, if $X \sim \text{Uniform}[a,b]$, then it’s pretty intuitive that $X$ shouldn’t take values from $\mathbb{R} \setminus [a,b]$.

Answer (score 1):

No.  Let $X$ be a random variable uniformly distributed on the interval $[0, 1]$, and let $Y$ be a random variable defined by $Y = X+1$ if $X = 1/2$, and $Y = X$ otherwise.  The PDFs of $X$ and $Y$ are identical, but only $Y$ can take on a value ($3/2$) for which its PDF is equal to zero.